# Using a variable to define a resource

Tags: java, android

I want to display 5 random dice, of the 6 sided variety. 
 I have code that generates 5 random integers between 1 and 6, and I have 5 ImageViews of dice.  They have ids set to: d6_image_view_1, d6_image_view_2, etc.  In the drawable folder, I have d1.jpg, d2.jpg, etc.  So if I want to change the second picture to a 4, I would do this:

```
ImageView d6ImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d6_image_view_2);
d6ImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.d4);
```

What if I have the numbers for the ImageView and drawable in variables? 
 Do I have to do a long, complicated nested if setup to get the right output?  Or can I somehow put those numbers right into the code?  Obviously this doesn't work:

```
int image = 2;
int picture = 4;
ImageView d6ImageView(image) = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d6_image_view_(image));
d6ImageView(image).setImageResource(R.drawable.d(picture));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no dynamic variables in Java. Java variables have to be declared in the source code. So a solution could be to make two arrays of integers for both drawable resources and view id's

For example

```
int[] resourceIds = new int[] { R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.d4, R.drawable.d5, R.drawable.d6 }

int[] viewIds = new int[] { R.id.d6_image_view_1, R.id.d6_image_view_2, R.id.d6_image_view_3, R.id.d6_image_view_4, R.id.d6_image_view_5, R.id.d6_image_view_6 }
```

Then you could do

```
int image = 2;
int picture = 4;
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(viewIds[image]);
imgView.setImageResource(resourceIds[picture]);
```